# Confirmatory Factor Analysis (CFA) concrete estimation example

Tags: psychometrics, confirmatory-factor

I'm looking for a simple concrete example of Confirmatory Factor Analysis. What are the precise steps?

What I (think) understand so far:

1. Get data (random sample).
2. Bring in a theory along the line of

   > This unobserved variable $\eta_1$ is correlated to the observed variables $x,y,z$ and not to $v, w$, $\eta_1$ is correlated to $v, w, z$ (and not $x,y$).

The unobserved variables are chosen because theory predicts they cause the others and are called *latent* or *underlying* factors.

3. [Compute](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118056/confirmatory-factor-analysis-without-the-raw-data) the covariance matrix of $x,y,z,v,w$.
4. Fit a linear models... (but the $\eta$'s are the dependent variable (but still unbserved) so how can we know the coefficients on the observed variables (which are called loadings $\lambda$)?)
5. Compute (how?) the implied covariance matrix and compare to the actual covariance matrix use some kind of a statistic to estimate how likely the observed difference between that matrices is due to random chance.

Comment: That's a big question to answer. Have you looked at any books or papers?

Comment: Blow my own trumpet for a minute: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16629301